# Prevent Migration Rollback Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In real world we have a bunch of important data in our databases. And in Frameworks like `ROR` it can be deleted by just a single command (`rake db:migrate VERSION=0`). Is there any `config` or `function` that verifies that

> "actually you mean to drop the whole database ? or you just did it
>   unintentionally "

. After this warning ,

> User may enter yes or no

. And furthur procedure completes.
If a function/config like this exists , then kindly let us know and if not then kindly guide us

Comment: @Rob i updated my question , It mistakenly wrote it rails instead of rake

Comment: in 2021, you can do `rails` instead of `rake`

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy workaround - just create a migration where the down method is defined as follows

```
def down
  raise IrreversibleMigration 
end
```

Comment: should this be place in every migration# ?I think it'll be in the last one right ?

Comment: Not every migration. If it was a new project and I was concerned about this, I'd make a migration immediately that had a blank #up action and that #down action.

Comment: doesnot this matters that where to place this specific migration , i mean it this is in the middle then , at rake db:migrate VERSION=0 it will delete all the migrations until it reach at the specific migration (having config)

Comment: yep, that's right. Except that you having down migrations is a useful feature, you don't want to disable it because it prevents you from rolling back a release. Many changes have a perfectly reasonable down migration.

Comment: and if you place it on the last migration, then nobody can back out anything ever, and that's not usually the right answer. Only a few migrations are of the form you are worried about.

Comment: It throws exception `NameError: uninitialized constant StopMigrationDeletion::IrreversibleMigration` which means it's a trick ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106502/discussion-between-rob-and-imrannaqvi).